# How can I style the backface of a rotated element?

Tags: css

I have a `figure` which is rotatable (to any degree via user input) this rotation visibly rotates using the `transition` property. When this element is rotated by more than 90deg/-90deg the backface of the element is visible. I'm wanting to style this usually-hidden side of the element differently to how the front side is styled, but I'm not sure how this can be achieved.

```css
figure {
    background:#fff;
    color:#000;
    border:1px solid #000;
    transition:1s;
}

figure:hover {
    transform:rotateY(180deg);
}
```

#### Current Style (Browser Default):

[image: Current example]

#### Desired Style:

[image: Desired example]

Is there any way I can style the backface of an element differently to the front?

Here is a basic JSFiddle demo of this rotation (on hover): http://jsfiddle.net/Y89t3/

Comment: If you haven't already, I highly recommend reading http://24ways.org/2010/intro-to-css-3d-transforms/

Comment: @j08691 I've already looked through [Github-hosted version](http://desandro.github.io/3dtransforms/docs/introduction.html) of that before, it's a great introduction. For the card flip (which is similar to the basic example I've given), that uses a second element as the backface. This isn't really what I'm after for this though, I just want to be able to change the backface of the same element without clogging up the HTML.

Comment: Why just not display a 'black' box ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If the background doesn't need to reproduce the front, it can be done with a pseudo element:

### [webkit demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vals/fSw2E/)

The CSS is:

```
.test { 
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    position: relative;
    left: 30px;
    top: 30px;
    background-color: lightgreen;
    transition: all 2s linear;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.test:after {
    content: '';
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    background: linear-gradient(to right, black, transparent);
    -webkit-transform: rotateY( 180deg );
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}


.container:hover .test {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY( 180deg );
}
```

Most of it is auxiliary stuff. The only interesting issues are setting the pseudo element rotated 180 deg (as the backface) and setting backface visibility to hidden.

I have tried to keep the original content of the div visible, and found something that I don't understand; I will post that as a question

Comment: Hmm I imagine this is the best way to do it. I hadn't considered using pseudo selectors at all! Thank you.

Comment: @vals Was your question related to the background color? Could you link it here?

Comment: @Casimir here is the link to the question I made   https://stackoverflow.com/q/17533719/1926369

Comment: This doesn't seem to work anymore. The backface-hidden on the parent also hides the pseudo element

Answer (score 1):

go here, this will show you how to do it http://desandro.github.io/3dtransforms/docs/card-flip.html

Comment: That uses a second element for the backface and this isn't really what I'm after. If I had 50 elements which could be rotated at the same time, having to add 50 more elements is just going to be messy. I'm ideally looking for a CSS solution.

Comment: not sure what you mean, but that is mostly css used in that example