# Strange behaviour in a transition to element backface (Chrome)

Tags: css, google-chrome, transform

I don't know exactly what title to set for this question.

I have some experiments with 3d transforms and backface visibility: hidden.

I was trying to set an element backface visible, but overlayed with a pseudo-element of itself, this one backface-visibility: hidden:

This is the CSS:

```
.test { 
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    position: relative;
    left: 30px;
    top: 30px;
    background-color: lightgreen;
    transition: all 2s linear;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.test:after {
    content: '';
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    background: linear-gradient(to right, black, transparent);
    -webkit-transform: rotateY( 180deg );
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}


.container:hover .test {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY( 180deg );
}
```

### [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vals/LbJBy/)

The element rotates, and for the transition duration you can see the TEST letters backwards thru the backface masks. And then, the effect disappears.

Anyone can explain what is happening here ?

EDITING:

I haven't been clear about what I wanted and what I get, and what I don't understand.

I was trying to have the pseudo element to act as a layer on the backside of the element. That's why:

1. The element has backface visible.
2. The pseudo element has backface hidden
3. the pseudo element has some alpha.

So, when you are seeing the front, you see only the element, normal.
When you see the back, you see the element (reversed, of course) with the color changed by the pseudo element. (that is visible because that is its front face)

Now, I expected that to succeed or fail, bt I didn't expect (and can't understand) why it works **during** the transition and stops working at the end of the transition. And, also, **what** property is beeing transitioned here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Imagine two sheets of paper with text printed on one side. You put them together with the text sides facing each other. Now rotate them: You don't see any text, do you? :)

`.test:after` is above `.test` and facing it (`rotateY( 180deg )`). Since the backface is hidden you don't see `.test:after`. When `.test` is rotated  `.test:after` is rotated with it, like the two pages. So as long as the backface of `.test` is not hidden, you won't see `.test:after`.

The flickering you notice is some kind of rendering issue.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, but I notice that I haven't make my point clear enough. I have added a further explanation to the question

Comment: I exactly understood what you wanted. Again: The pseudo element is not visible because the main element's backface is visible. It's tricky, I know. :)