# Why is rotating element not showing?

Tags: html, css, transformation, css-transforms

Trying to create a rotating "card". The cover, inside-left, and inside-right all work fine. The back however is giving me issues. I applied the same rules to each panel so I don't know where the bug is coming from.

```css
.scene {
  margin-top: 10em;
  margin-left: 20em;
  width: 20em;
  height: 20em;
  perspective: 40em;
}

.cube {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  animation: spinning 12s infinite;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-origin: left;
}

@keyframes spinning {
  from {
    transform: translateY(5em) rotateY(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: translateY(5em) rotateY(-360deg);
  }
}

.front-left {
  width: 60%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  line-height: 10em;
  text-align: center;
  transform-origin: left;
}

.panel-1 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-style: solid;
  position: absolute;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.cover {
  background-color: blue;
}

.left {
  background-color: red;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.right-back {
  width: 60%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  line-height: 10em;
  text-align: center;
  transform: rotateY(130deg);
  transform-origin: left;
}

.panel-2 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-style: solid;
  position: absolute;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.end {
  background-color: blue;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.right {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="scene">
  <div class="cube">
    <div class="front-left">
      <div class="panel-1 cover">cover</div>
      <div class="panel-1 left">inner left</div>
    </div>
    <div class="right-back">
      <div class="panel-2 end">back</div>
      <div class="panel-2 right">inner right</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

here is a fiddle of the code. https://jsfiddle.net/7xtv90as/

I suspect it might be because a transform is applied to the parent container but I am not sure.

Comment: the "end" div is still not displaying, should be blue like the cover and say "back". It's really puzzling.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I style the backface of a rotated element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17529982/how-can-i-style-the-backface-of-a-rotated-element)